# "See + noun + that is/are + adj" OR "See + noun + adj"

Tags: verbs, adjectives

Is the following sentance correct?

> Although, sometimes you see curves **that are** a little bit noisier and a little bit messier than this.

Could I say this one instead?

> Although, sometimes you see curves a little bit noisier and a little bit messier than this.

Is the second form often used in conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to both questions.  The first form is correct and the second is sometimes used in conversation.  I think most native speakers (at least of AmE) would consider those to be pretty equal as far as meaning and being normal conversation.